# Fitnesse - runner process not starting

Tags: fitnesse

I have a test in fitnesse which used to work, but when I got into work today the test did not start at all. As soon as I press test I get the "0 errors 0 warrings..." text on the top of the test. Looking in the source control software, I can not find any changes to the test, or to anything related to it. I have noticed that the runner process does not start when I run the test. Other tests seem to work fine, and I can copy the tables from the test which is not working into an other test and everything is fine. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My standard answer in this situation is, "have you checked your classpath?"

I say this, as typically when this sort of thing happens, it is that the !path doesn't point to the stuff you need, whether it be FitNesse.jar or your own custom code.

Also, do you get an output page where you can check the classpath?  i doubt it, but that can help diagnose classpath issues.